# How to fix the error 0x800700c1 when launching `powershell.exe' in Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-terminal

Recently I got the following error in my Windows Terminal:

```
[error 0x800700c1 when launching "C:\Users\Dry-C Desktop\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.PowerShell_8wekyb3d8bbwe\pwsh.exe"]
```

[How do Image of the Issue - error 0x800700c1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ5gp.png)

How do I want to know, how can I solve it to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the `Windows Terminal` `settings.json` config file by adding the following:

1 - Find the settings on:
Windows Terminal `arrow down` nearby the tab(s), Click to the `settings button`, and Click to `Open JSON File` field.

2 - Add this command to the config file like the example below:

```
"commandline": "\"C:\\Users\\Your Machine actual Username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\Microsoft.PowerShell_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\pwsh.exe\""
```

The original `Windows Terminal` config:

```
{
   ...
   "guid": "{574e775e-4f2a-5b96-ac1e-a2962a402336}",
   "hidden": false,
   "name": "PowerShell",
   "source": "Windows.Terminal.PowershellCore",
},
...
```

After Change:

```
{
   ...
   "guid": "{574e775e-4f2a-5b96-ac1e-a2962a402336}",
   "hidden": false,
   "name": "PowerShell",
   "source": "Windows.Terminal.PowershellCore",
   "commandline": "\"C:\\Users\\Your Machine actual Username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\Microsoft.PowerShell_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\pwsh.exe\"",
},
...
```

Don't forget to change `You Machine Actual Username` in the `commandline` field.

Ref: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/6082#issuecomment-1001226003

Or you can follow this blog suggestion that works as well:
https://blog.darrenjrobinson.com/error-0x800700c1-when-launching-cprogram-filespowershell7pwsh-exe/

Comment: I was just about to post a similar solution following this blog post (https://blog.darrenjrobinson.com/error-0x800700c1-when-launching-cprogram-filespowershell7pwsh-exe/) - note: you can also specify the path in the settings of windows terminal

Comment: Cool, I read your blog and it worked perfectly too!

Thank you @GuentherSchmitz!

Thank you for your suggestion and if I'll have the same problem again I'll resort to your blog post!