# Path missing in User Variables

Tags: ubuntu, path, system-variable, user-variables

Deleted Path in User Variables for Pc1, what can I do? and I keep getting [error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching `ubuntu2204.exe'] when opening terminal app,

I also copied values of Path in System Variables to new Path variable in User Variables. How can I restore my original Path and how can I solve the ubuntu error?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue
[refer to the best answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70548014/how-to-fix-the-error-0x800700c1-when-launching-powershell-exe-in-windows-termi)
with replacing the path to the path i found for ubuntu wsl mine was :

> C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu22.04LTS_2204.1.23.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc
> i used windows search to locate it

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the app path in Settings UI from `ubuntu2204.exe` to be `wsl -d Ubuntu-22.04`, which worked originally in another system-created profile.